# Scrolling from navbar list of items to element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

Like the title says, I want to click on a navbar item and then scroll down to the `id` element of it.

This is my list:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="">About</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="">Contact</a></li>   
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <p class="navbar-text" id="name">Daniel Ramirez</p> 
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

I want to scroll to id elements named `#home` , `#about`, `#portfolio` and `#contact`.

Here's my jQuery code, which isn't working:

```
$('ul > li').eq(0).click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make these changes

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Home</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript: void(0)">About</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript: void(0)">Contact</a></li>   
   </ul>
```

in above change the href

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul > li').click(function() { 
    var srollToElement = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + srollToElement).offset().top  }, 1000);  
      });
});
```

in above there is relation to Text between opening and closing i.e. if we want scrolling for portfolio then we should have portfolio element in small and the Text b/w opening closing should match. Though I did make a to lowercase call.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Can you tell me what does `javascript: void(0)` does?

Comment: It simply stops normal behavior of <a> tag, and return undefine